# How to turn off only the obfuscation in Android R8?

Tags: android, android-r8

I use Android Studio 3.3 Canary 5, Gradle 4.9, gradle plugin 3.3.0-alpha05

```
minifyEnabled true
useProguard false
proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
```

Does't work.

---

**Edit:**

@JakeWharton: "You use ProGuard configurations for this, not a Gradle DSL. Disable shrinking with -dontshrink, disable obfuscation with -dontobfuscate, and disable optimization with -dontoptimize."

### TLDL

> proguard-rules.pro

```
-dontshrink
-dontobfuscate
-dontoptimize
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Following [this answer](https://www.reddit.com/r/androiddev/comments/bae6ny/r8_and_proguard/ekb4m7d/), I was able to solve this issue. Instead of editing the `build.gradle` file, I added `-dontobfuscate` to the `proguard-rules.pro` file. (You can configure a different `proguard` rules file for debug and release builds.) This skipped the obfuscation step and allowed me to make shrink'd debug builds with R8.

Comment: From the link: @JakeWharton: "You use ProGuard configurations for this, not a Gradle DSL. Disable shrinking with -dontshrink, disable obfuscation with -dontobfuscate, and disable optimization with -dontoptimize."

Comment: We shouldn't use **gradle.properties** for this?

Answer (score 17):

In your `gradle.properties` file, add this line

```
 android.enableR8=false
```

This worked for me.

Comment: useProguard will soon be deprecated, any idea how we could fix this issue ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57736108/proguard-problem-after-updating-to-android-gradle-plugin-3-5 without disabling R8?

Comment: This isn't deprecated?

Comment: This turns off R8 completely, both obfuscation and shrinking.

Comment: This is now removed in Android Gradle Plugin 7.0

Answer (score 0):

`build.gradle`

```java
buildTypes {
    release {
        shrinkResources false
        minifyEnabled true // R8 or ProGuard will be enabled.
        proguardFiles 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
    debug {
        shrinkResources false
        minifyEnabled false // R8 or ProGuard will be disabled.
    }
}
```

*This answer does not demonstrate how to disable obfuscation within R8. It instead shows how to disable obfuscation at the build level.*

I found setting `minifyEnabled` to false in `build.gradle` disables R8 and thus removes obfuscation. **Obligatory reminder:** Be cautious disabling obfuscation as it will mean the source will not be cloaked whatsoever.

Comment: This not answer the question "How to turn off *only* the obfuscation in Android R8?" Seems to me an AI nonsense comment

Comment: @norbDEV This isn't an AI generated answer. I came across this question when trying to figure out how to disable obfuscation. However, I understand that my answer isn't directly related to the question so I'll edit it to reflect that.