# Android Studio 3.4 seems to be stuck on transformClassesAndResourcesWithR8

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

Just upgraded to Android Studio 3.4 and am trying to compile my apks for the first time with it.  Seems to be stuck forever at:

[image]

Shall I give this up as a bad job, or be patient?

Comment: I had similar issues. Just updated gradle to 5.2.1 and all issues gone.

Comment: @VikasPatidar I'm confused... in `File > Project Structure > Project` my gradle version is stated as `5.1.1`.  But the latest gradle version according to the following is only `3.4.0`: https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/gradle-plugin  EDIT aah that's the *plugin*... gradle itself is https://gradle.org/releases/ ... do I update the gradle version just by typing the new version number in `File > Project Structure > Project`?

Comment: That's 3.4.0 is gradle plugin version for Android, you need to change only gradle version. from 5.1.1 to 5.2.1

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57736108/proguard-problem-after-updating-to-android-gradle-plugin-3-5
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51860843/how-to-turn-off-only-the-obfuscation-in-android-r8

Answer (score 10):

No, I gave up after 1 hour (had to force close Android Studio), log out and back in again.  I then noted that R8 is enabled by default, so I disabled it as [per this](https://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:3x-TbApCAOcJ:https://developer.android.com/studio/preview/features%20&cd=1&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=uk#R8-enabled) and now it's back to normal (using ProGuard rather than R8 though).

EDIT I tried enabling R8 again and this time I got an error message `Out of memory: Java heap space`, with a suggestion to increase the amount of memory allocated to Gradle by using the following line in `gradle.properties`:

```
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx1024m
```

... and it worked!  Seems to compile a lot quicker using R8 compared to Proguard.

Comment: I was using gradle-wrapper.properties instead of **gradle.properties** but this works

Comment: Note: This setting can be [defined for different scopes](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/build_environment.html). In particular in can be [defined on system level](https://mrhaki.blogspot.com/2015/10/gradle-goodness-setting-global.html) in the file `gradle.properties` in `GRADLE_USER_HOME` which usually is `USER_HOME/.gradle`. This solution works; I wonder why it is necessary and does not work "out of the box".

Answer (score 5):

Even after having `16GB-RAM/256SSD/Core-i7` configuration, I ran into similar issue while building project in release mode on `Android Studio 3.4` version with `gradle-5.1.1`, but after updating to `gradle-5.2.1` all issues gone. Just go to `File` menu and open the `Project Structure` dialog to update the version.
[image]

Comment: I tried upgrading gradle version as suggested, but I still get the `Out of memory: Java heap space` error as per my answer... for me this is only solved by including `org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx1024m` in `gradle.properties`.