# proguard problem after updating to android gradle plugin 3.5

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, proguard

I save the `json` presentation of some objects as cache in my app. I had no problem after updating each release of the app and `json` objects was correctly converted to java objects. After updating to android gradle plugin 3.5 (Adding this line):

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.0'
```

When I create the release apk, It seems that it can't convert the `json` string to java objects and it seems that the obfuscated names has changed. When I revert it to gradle plugin 3.4.2, everything is OK. So what is the problem and how can I fix that?

Comment: can't you add that json files as exception in proguard rules

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57156980/7254873

Comment: @ManojPerumarath, the problem is that the obfuscated objects have been saved as cache and if I exclude them now, saved jason objects cannot convert to java objects.

Comment: Its the Anroid R8 which is disabling the progaurd, since it has different algorithm even though your objects are obfuscated they are not deserializable anymore. I assume Android did not consider this use case. See the answers below from Bhaven Shah for the fix.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I should exclude cached objects from obfuscating but temporarily I disabled `R8` and enabled proguard, by adding this line to `gradle.properties` file:

```
android.enableR8=false
```

And adding this line to app `build.gradle` file:

```
useProguard true
minifyEnabled true
```

And the problem solved.

Comment: Does this issue still occur as Google is going to remove useProguard and use only android.enableR8 . "WARNING: DSL element 'useProguard' is obsolete and will be removed soon. Use 'android.enableR8' in gradle.properties to switch between R8 and Proguard"

Comment: @user12865,  the issue still occurs, but as you said, `useProguard` is going to be removed and the temporary solution won't work anymore.

Answer (score 6):

I also got the same error.

And I found that it's an error of enabledR8 which is used to reduce app size.

and It is true predefined. So by set value, a false error was gone.

---

Set it value false of r8 in gradle.properties file.

> **android.enableR8=false**

Comment: This answer makes sense, thank you. So basically R8 is the new way of compressing, minifying and obfuscating the code, hence it automatically disables progaurd rules.  This created a havoc all my serialized data no longer readable. Whew. Big Thank you for the quick answer.

Comment: @MGDeveloper Google is going to get rid of useProguard property soon, and we will need to enable R8 in that case. Not sure how long this can ben done