# Android Studio 3.5 : This method contains native references and will be minified. [KeepMissing]

Tags: android, android-ndk, android-r8, android-studio-3.5

yesteday I update Android Studio to the new 3.5 version. After restarting my PC, Android Studio wasn't able to compile my app any more. I have 3 errors like this:

> App.java:29: Error: This method contains native references and will be minified. [KeepMissing]

in two different Java files, where I call some native methods

I know that version 3.5 has R8 as default code obfuscator, so in my build.gradle I commented useProguard false/true from my debug/release build type.
It looks like this now:

```
buildTypes {
    debug {
        debuggable true
        jniDebuggable true
        signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        minifyEnabled false //shrink
        //useProguard false //obfuscate
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        ndk {
            debuggable = true
        }
    }
    release {
        debuggable false
        jniDebuggable false
        signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        minifyEnabled true //shrink
        //useProguard false //obfuscate
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        ndk {
            debuggable = false
        }
    }
}
```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Update your proguard-rules.pro to disable obfuscation either completely or for specific classes/methods. See e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51860843/how-to-turn-off-only-the-obfuscation-in-android-r8

Comment: Thank you for your reply! I tried adding -dontobfuscate as the first code line in my proguard-rules.pro file, but I keep continue getting the mensioned error. Here is the complete log of the error:
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

C:\[packagename]\App.java:29: Error: This method contains native references and will be minified. [KeepMissing]
      public native String stringFromJNI();
                           ~~~~~~~~~~
* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

Comment: Mmm something strange, i commented all references to any native C code, and now I get other errors, like:
LoginViewModel.java:158: Error: Missing permissions required by TelephonyManager.getDeviceId: android.permission.READ_PRIVILEGED_PHONE_STATE [MissingPermission]
          return  ((TelephonyManager)getApplication().getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE)).getDeviceId(); whitch I requested my fragment.

And 
StartupActivity.java:91: Error: Overriding method should call super.onSaveInstanceState [MissingSuperCall]

Previously they where only warnings, now fatal errors?

Comment: I just solved by deleting .gradle, .idea folders and all .iml files in my project!

Comment: Check this thread [Android/java: Transition / Migration from ProGuard to R8?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52921486/8034839) to see if it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Proguard rules are changed for a lot of libraries since R8 is added. For example, Moshi has updated rules: **https://github.com/square/moshi/blob/master/moshi/src/main/resources/META-INF/proguard/moshi.pro** so it can work with R8. 
Please check other libraries and add new rules