# Flutter build release APK get NoSuchMethodException error

Tags: java, android, flutter

I encountered a problem when upgrading the Flutter SDK. I used to use **1.9.x** (there is no problem below). Now I upgrade to **v1.12.13 + hotfix.9** or **1.17.0** to reproduce this problem (I have only tried These two versions), the problem is as follows:

Now I use the **v1.17.0** SDK to create a plug-in, and then use the reflection call method in the plug-in. The code is as follows:

[Flutterplugin17Plugin.java](https://gist.github.com/liusilong/bceeb70711380b963f2b9baa3f9f4943)

```java
  @Override
  public void onMethodCall(@NonNull MethodCall call, @NonNull Result result) {
    if (call.method.equals("personName")) { // Reflection call method
      person.execute(call.method);
      result.success("success");
    }
  }
```

The Person class as follows:

[Person.java](https://gist.github.com/liusilong/a66010df2c45063fa32737a510e4a86e)

```java
public class Person {
    private static final String TAG = "Person";

    // This method will be called by reflection
    public void personName() {
        Log.e(TAG, "personName: call personName method....");
    }

    public void execute(String methodName) {
        try {
            Method method = Person.class.getDeclaredMethod(methodName);
            method.invoke(Person.this);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Part of Flutter's code is as follows

[flutterplugin17.dart](https://gist.github.com/liusilong/493026e3e84ba050115ca9d094fb7d14)

```dart
static Future<void> callMethod() async{
  await _channel.invokeMethod("personName");
}

// The method is called when the button is clicked
await Flutterplugin17.callMethod();
```

**Then if it is run directly (Click the debug button to run in Android Studio), it is OK, and the reflection method can be correctly called.**

**Using Android Studio to package Release APK (release) is also no problem.**

> Build -> Generate Signed Bundle or APK

**But when I use the Flutter command to package the APK (release), the reflection method in the plugin cannot be called at this time. adb logcat is as follows:**

> Packaging commands : flutter build apk --release

[image: error.png]

**There is also a situation where the above problem occurs. When another library is used in a plugin and this library is obfuscated, this time the above error will occur if the method in this obfuscated library is called.**

flutter doctor:

[image: doctor.jpg]

I don’t know why this problem occurs when using the flutter command to package the release APK, thanks.

github repository： https://github.com/liusilong/flutter_plugin_17

---

I used the following three ways to package apk and then opened these apk in android studio for comparison:

1. The flutter version is **1.17**, packaged with Android studio (Build -> Generate Signed Bundle or APK), the dex file is parsed as follows:

[image: image.png]

2. The flutter version is **1.17**, packaged with Flutter commands(flutter build apk --release), the dex file is parsed as follows:

[image: image.png]

3. The flutter version is **1.9.1+hotfix.6**, packaged with Flutter commands(flutter build apk --release), the dex file is parsed as follows:

[image: image.png]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know what the problem is. I am using Android Studio3.6, the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/shrink-code) says **When you use Android Studio 3.4 or Android Gradle plugin 3.4.0 and higher, R8 is the default compiler**

There are two ways to solve it：

> add **proguard-rules.pro** file to `project/app/proguard-rules.pro`

**The first solution(Not using R8):**

1. In the `project/gradle.properties` file, Set this property `android.enableR8` to `false`, as follow：

```
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx1536M
android.enableR8=false
android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true
```

2. In the `project/app/proguard-rules.pro` file, customize the code to keep:

```
-keep class com.lsl.flutterplugin17.* {*;}
```

3. In the `project/app/build.gradle` file, add the code as follow:

```
android {
   ...

    buildTypes {
        release {
            ...
            // add new line
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'

        }
    }
   ...
}
```

Use flutter command `flutter build apk --release` to pack, the dex file is parsed as follows：

[image: image.png]

**The second solution(Use R8):**

1.In the project/app/proguard-rules.pro file, add the code as follow:

```
-dontobfuscate
-dontshrink
```

2. In the `project/app/build.gradle` file, add the code as follow:

```
android {
   ...

    buildTypes {
        release {
            ...
            // add new line
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'

        }
    }
   ...
}
```

Use flutter command `flutter build apk --release` to pack, the dex file is parsed as follows：

[image: image.png]

- [How to turn off only the obfuscation in Android R8?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51860843/how-to-turn-off-only-the-obfuscation-in-android-r8)
- [Shrink, obfuscate, and optimize your app](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/shrink-code)

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you need to accept the android licenses to build a release apk?